# Django2.0; still cannot get how redirect works

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I still don't get how redirect works.

For now, I use this way to redirect.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('main:index'))
```

and this way works.

And now I'm creating another page, and what I want to do is to redirect to the same page after I submit the form data.

view.py is like this

```
def add_comment(request, pk):

    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = CommentForm()
    else:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.user = request.user
            new_comment.save()


            return redirect('add_comment', pk=entry.id)
    return render(request, 'main/add_comment.html', {'form': form, 'entry': entry, 'comments': comments})
```

urls.py is like this

```
path('add_comment/<int:pk>', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
```

I can enter this page, but after I submit the form, this error happens.

> NoReverseMatch at /add_comment/5
>
> Reverse for 'add_comment' not found. 'add_comment' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>
> Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_comment/5

even though I can enter this url page, I cannot redirect to the same page.

How am I wrong with this? Also what is the recommended way to redirect to a page?

Comment: Side note are you sure that the model is being filled out correctly? After you add more information to the model you will need to call `new_comment.save()`. If you are not filling out the model correctly it may not be able to navigate to it at that point. Does the redirect work when you navigate to a page that you are sure does work, i.e. `/` or `/google.com`?

Comment: oops, sorry I deleted the line when I post code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change this:

```
return redirect('add_comment', pk=entry.id)
```

to this:

```
return redirect('main:add_comment', pk=entry.id))
```

Assuming that all your URLs are in the same namespace. If your `index` url is defined in the same list as your `add_comment` URL then they will be sharing the `main` namespace.